# SSRS Format Tablix TextBox as Time Not Working?

Tags: datetime, formatting, ssrs-2012

I have a stored proc as follows:

```
SELECT TBL1.[ID]
     ,TBL1.[FKTBL1]
     --,TBL1.TimelineDate
  ,CONVERT(DATE, TBL1.TimelineDate) AS 'TimelineDate'
  ,CONVERT(TIME(0), TBL1.TimelineDate) AS 'TimelineTime'
     ,TBL1.TimelineActivity
 FROM [dbo].[tblTBL1Timeline] TBL1
 WHERE TBL1.[FKTBL1] = @PARMID
```

This is the dataset for a tablix in SSRS.  The date field is formatting fine, but the time comes out as 0:00:00 even if I have a time in the underlying results.  I can run the stored proc in SSMS and get the results, but in SSRS it won't format right. If I choose 1:30 PM I get 0:00:00.  If I choose the format on the text field (in SSRS) 13:30 I get error.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  I would like it to be formatted as 1:30 PM.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy answer for this.  I changed my proc as follows:

```
SELECT TBL1.[ID]
     ,TBL1.[FKTBL1]
     --,TBL1.TimelineDate
  ,CONVERT(DATE, TBL1.TimelineDate) AS 'TimelineDate'
  ,TBL1.TimelineDate AS 'TimelineTime'
  ,TBL1.TimelineActivity
 FROM [dbo].[tblTBL1Timeline] TBL1
 WHERE TBL1.[FKTBL1] = @PARMID
```

This means I am pulling the full datetime field for the 'TimelineTime' field.  Now, when I format it's corresponding textbox in SSRS, I can set it to 1:30 PM and it formats like it should!

Whew!

Comment: I was just about to comment top that effect. There is probably no need to even use two columns in your SQL, just use TBL1.TimelineDate in two columns in your report, format one as a date and the other as a time.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking that.  Now I'm on to a new problem, where I've got a tablix with 3 columns, but it's got column grouping, so that the first column is labels. The 2nd 2 columns have data, but if there are no records their borders don't show. This isn't good, because it makes the report look odd.  I'll likely need to post this as a new thread. I don't have any visibility filters set, and can shrink is no.

Comment: You'll need to ask a new question and make sure to include as much information as possible

Comment: I know. It's going to take a bit to document the nature of the tablix, which is why I'm trying to troubleshoot as much as possible, before I ask the question.